How to compensate for the phase shift caused by a bandpass filter?
I am trying to simulate a 10-band graphic equalizer based on 10 octaves. For each channel, I tried to cascade 4 -20 dB active low-pass filter and 4 +20 dB active high pass filters (I cascaded these many filters so that the phase shift equations are somewhat simpler and identical to simple all pass filters) to form a 80 dB band-pass. But now the issue is about the phase shift, which I thought would be simpler if I cascaded these many filters.
The phase shift caused by a low-pass filter is $$-\arctan(\omega RC) $$
whereas the phase shift caused by an all-pass filter incorporating a low-pass filter is $$-2\arctan(\omega RC)$$
I thought cascading these all-pass filters with low pass filter would negate the phase shift, but later realized that they are rather creating more phase shift, since both of them are causing the same lagging phase shift. Is there any other way to design an active pass filter that could compensate this phase shift?
Another thing to know is that, does these cascading 8 filters(excluding the phasers) cause serious issue by delaying the time between input and output? I could use Butterworth filters as well, but their phase shift equation seemed a bit complex.

if this is for audio, then phase shift is irrelevant, inaudible.

Yes I'm trying to simulate for audio. But shouldn't this phase shift cause incoherence between different frequency components?

You would expect the change in relationship between different frequencies, causing a change in waveform shape, to be audible, wouldn't you? AFAIK, listening experiments have shown it to be inaudible. I don't have any citations to hand, perhaps somebody could spend a few minutes on a sutable search engine. As Andy's answer below is true (summarised as filters are causal, output must lag input), and that countless audio systems use filter-based tone controls without problems, this supports what I assert.

Putting a suitable allpass filter behind a lowpass/highpass filter equalizes the time delay (=linear phase shift) of all frequency components present inside the passband. There are certain situations where equal delay/linear phase is important but I don't know if it really makes a noticeable difference with audio/music sources.

if two different frequency components lag differently then shouldn't the output waveform be completely different from the input?

Yes, the waveform is different, but the ear perceives the sounds as the same. It's as if the ear is doing frequency analysis, and throwing away the phase. In fact, for estimation of direction of arrival, the relative phase between the ears is only important for very low frequencies. For a single ear, the phase at various frequencies appears to be unimportant. The human brain percieves all sorts of things differently to how a physics instrument records them - colour constancy with variable background lighting for instance, and the same sound for same frequency content but different waveforms.

And if you're worried about audible phase, you had better look up how much gets thrown away in lossy audio encoding like MP3. I cannot discern any difference between the original audio, and MP3 encoding with 192 kbit/s or more encoding rate (but I am not a 'golden ear'). I suggest you test yourself critically. It uses all sorts of temporal masking, to not bother encoding sounds at frequencies and times we will not be able to perceive.

Where it will matter if if you have two separate audio chains, to two speakers in close proximity, say a mid-range and a bass speaker each with their own amplifiers, and you could get waveform cancellation if the two sources of the same frequency drove the two speakers out of phase.

Filters create a natural time-lag between input and output. This is most readily seen in low-pass filters so, what you are asking for is realistically impossible to achieve. This statement doesn't just apply to electronics but to any mechanical system too.

I don't have any issue if all the frequency components lag equally but they lag differently based on their frequency and that causes a difference between the input and output. I want to minimize the disparity

@MSKB unfortunately, you are not going to get what you want. The best that can be achieved is a fairly constant time delay from 0 Hz up to a frequency that is lower than the cut-off frequency but, at the expense of a low quality factor. Try looking up Bessel filters to see what I mean.

I'm curious how does practical graphic equalizers deal with this issue?

I mean, the time delay from speaker across the room to the ear means that all sorts of spectral phase shifts happen and, do you notice those things? If you recorded the speaker output close to the speaker and also tried it further away, apart from the obvious amplitude reduction, the waveforms won't bear hardly any similarity for complex audio.

I just want one clarification about an issue, let me elaborate lets assume the for an audio the 1kHz component has a phase shift of 45° and that of 2kHz is nearly 90°. Doesn't that distort the whole audio input to something totally different? if not then I guess I wouldn't have to fix much about the circuit I'm trying to build

It makes absolutely no difference to the perception of sound @MSKB
